# BASH Base64 Encode script not encoding right

Tags: linux, bash, variables, base64

I am trying to get a base64 encode to work and output to a variable in a bash script.  The regular cli syntax is:

```
echo -ne "\0myuser@myhost.com\0mypass" | base64
```

But when I try putting this into a variable in a script it outputs, but a very small encoding, so I know it's not working. My code in the script is:

```
auth=$(echo -ne "\0$user@$host\0$pass" | base64);
```

I know it has something to do with the quotes, but I've tried a myriad of thing's with different quotes and singles and backslashes with no go.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: A bit more for the info. This should output with the user/pass/host above:

```
AG15dXNlckBteWhvc3QuY29tAG15cGFzcw==
```

But in the script it outputs:

```
LW5lIAo=
```

Comment: Are you sure `$user`, `$host` and `$pass` are set? Sorry for a stupid question, but gotta rule out the obvious stuff. Cause in my test it works allright, see http://pastebin.com/mSR64eEh

Comment: Dang IT!! Yeah their set, I do this just before doing that:
user="myuser"
pass="mypass"
host="myhost.com"

Comment: Saw my pastebin? Edited my comment, not sure before or after you answered :)

Comment: Yeah I looked at it before, that's what's wierd, I have that exact same thing and no go :(

Comment: Wait a second!! I just found my problem, I was using /bin/sh instead of bash, when I change it to /bin/bash it works fine!! What gives?! ha ha

Comment: Out of curiosity, which shell is linked to `/bin/sh` in your case?

Comment: Hmm, I would fair to say Bourne, but how do I check that? --- Sorry no Dash :)

Comment: See my answer. My gutfeeling says you are using Debian Squeeze, which all of a sudden started to default to `dash`. Source of major frustrations for many people.

Comment: @favoretti - Those many people shouldn't have put `#!/bin/sh` on a non-POSIX complaint script.

Comment: @jordanm - totally agree, although many beginners don't really feel the difference :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, I'll add this as an answer for the records's sake:

Problem was in having `/bin/sh` as a default interpreter shell, which I assume, in this case was `dash`.

Test script used:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=myuser
pass=mypass
host=myhost.com

auth=$(echo -ne "\0$user@$host\0$pass" | base64);

echo $auth
```

Results:

```
[51][00:33:22] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > echo -ne "\0myuser@myhost.com\0mypass" | base64 
AG15dXNlckBteWhvc3QuY29tAG15cGFzcw== 

[52][00:33:42] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > bash base64.sh
AG15dXNlckBteWhvc3QuY29tAG15cGFzcw== 

[53][00:33:46] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > dash base64.sh  
LW5lIAo=
```

Comment: Correct, I just found out it was linking to Dash. So what is the difference and what gives if I may ask?

Comment: `dash` is POSIX only + a few berkeley extensions. It somewhat resembles `ksh`, but has also not all the features and is far less featured than `bash`.

Comment: @jfreak53 In this case, it was probably the non-POSIX options to `echo`.

Comment: Hmm, show's you what I know, Dash is the default sh shell for Ubuntu 11 and beyond then :) thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo` and you shouldn't have to worry about differences between shells.

Comment: doesn't work with longer strings, there is a line break

Answer (score 14):

Different versions of `echo` behave very differently when you give them anything other than a plain string. Some interpret command options (like `-ne`), while some just print them as output; some interpret escape sequences in the string (even if not given a `-e` option), some don't.

If you want consistent behavior, use `printf` instead:

```
user=myuser
pass=mypass
host=myhost.com

auth=$(printf "\0%s@%s\0%s" "$user" "$host" "$pass" | base64)
```

As a bonus, since the password (and username and host) are in plain strings rather than the format string, it won't make a mess trying to interpret escape sequences in them (does your real password have a backslash in it?)